# Pdf is edited correctly only in Edge

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have created a pdf file with pdfbox (version 2.0.15) and it compiles with pdf/a. When I edit it with edge then everything is displayed correctly but when I edit it with XODO or adobe reader X or chrome then

- When I edit the values in text fields then I see squares instead of letters.
- All values in combo boxes are displayed incorrectly.
  Only labels are displayed correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding issue.

Comment: We need the PDF.

Comment: Please download it from https://gofile.io/?c=AcWXGW

Comment: This is weird... the encoding is identity, but ToUnicode is not. Could you try using a different font? E.g. the liberation sans font that comes with PDFBox? (See the CreatePDFA example for the resource URL)

Comment: Please download new file https://gofile.io/?c=URnZ03. I still face some problems with XODO. I do not have problem with edge and chrome.

Comment: Please download the latest file (https://gofile.io/?c=I2kneY) that conforms to the PDF/A-1b standard.

Comment: I just tried with the latest file, no problem with Adobe Reader DC. I did have the troubles you described with the original file. ("Business name" field)

Comment: You are right but If I try to edit with Adobe Reader DC then DC adds to PDF file extra fonts and also when I write to textfield or combobox then the fonts are different than the initial fonts (that I have embedded during the creation of file with pdfbox). Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know why Adobe does what it does. This effect also happens with the file generated by the CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java example. Btw Adobe also refuses to edit your file unless one clicks on the yellow bar and on the blue bar.